# ShowTypingMiddleware keeps showing indicator even after the message is sent

Tags: c#, botframework

Using The ShowTypingMiddleware in SDK **V4** ,Can someone further explain in a real example how the **delay** and **period** work.

 Ex: **ShowTypingMiddleware(0, 2000)**

**Delay**: Initial delay before sending first typing indicator 
**Period**: Rate at which additional typing indicators will be sent

From what i understood:

- Delay

  If the **Delay is 0** then when the bot is about to send a message to the user, there should be no delays and the indicator should show immediately just before sending out the message.
- Period

  [*Considering a **person typing** example*] 
    Is that for example when  someone pauses while writing a message than starts typing again?
   Meaning after the person starts  typing it will wait 2000ms before sending out the typing indicator again? 
   
  [*Considering the **bot** example*] 
   
  How does that translates for the bot? The bot does not ***pause***

  When will the Period indicator be effective for the bot?

**The Main issue I am facing is that, the bot keeps showing the typing indicator even after the message is sent. So the user keeps waiting**

This is happening on both **Messenger** and **DirectLine** Channels

Is that heppening because of me misunderstanding **Period** & **Delay** or is there something else ?

**UPDATE:** *Check below GIF* 
(Watch all of it, about 50 seconds, Notice that it does not always happen) 
 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having an active typing indicator after the bot has sent a message might be related to:
https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/3047

If you have extra work in the `OnTurnAsync` method, the Cancellation of the `ShowTypingMiddleware` will not be called in time. Because of this, it will still be able to send out a typing indicator activity after your bot has sent a message activity.

You could create a copy of the `ShowTypingMiddleware` and modify it so it checks if the bot has already responded when checking for the Cancellation.
https://github.com/jvanderbiest/echo-bot-typing-indicator/blob/master/CustomShowTypingMiddleware.cs#L90

Answer (score 1):

> From what i understood: Delay If the Delay is 0 then when the bot is
>   about to send a message to the user, there should be no delays and the
>   indicator should show immediately just before sending out the message.

Correct. The delay before sending out the typing indicator.

> Period
>   **[Considering a person typing example]**
>   Is that for example when someone pauses while writing a message than starts typing again? Meaning after the person starts typing it will wait 2000ms before sending out the typing indicator again?

Yes, but this is controlled by the channel+client (of course).

> **[Considering the bot example]** 
>   How does that translates for the bot? The bot does not pause  When
>   will the Period indicator be effective for the bot?

The bot will resend the typing activity after 2 seconds. It will keep doing this until it sends a message activity.

I find the [summary](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/1769403c82b76954d848bcf2d73a3d6409cde762/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ShowTypingMiddleware.cs#L11) in the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ShowTypingMiddleware class pretty helpful.

> The Main issue I am facing is that, the bot keeps showing the typing
>   indicator even after the message is sent. So the user keeps waiting 
>   This is happening on both Messenger and DirectLine Channels Is that
>   happening because of me misunderstanding Period & Delay or is there
>   something else ?

If you are sending a message activity, that should stop the typing activity. If not, something is wrong. If you can create a sample reproduction of this issue, I would be interested in trying to see if I could repro myself.

You can find more information on the typing activity schema [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botframework-sdk/blob/master/specs/botframework-activity/botframework-activity.md#typing-activity).

Comment: I am using the Virtual Assistant Template, you can install that template and use it. The typing indicator keep showing after a message activity is sent for some time then it stops, but it still shows for some time (a few seconds) before it stops. I am using it with the delay=0 and period = 300ms. So when the user receives a message the typing indicator keeps going for a couple of seconds then it stops, making the user keep waiting thinking something else will be sent

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. Are you using web sockets? Did you make the same change (for ShowTypingMiddleware) in both `DefaultAdapater` and `DefaultWebSocketAdapter`, or somewhere else? 300ms is well below the recommended minimum. That shouldn't be the cause (but again, it should be working as expected). I am not able to reproduce the issue in my VA. Are you artificially causing a delay in your code to test this behavior (I am)?

Comment: Both DefaultAdapter and DefaultWebSocketAdapter have the same settings. I am not artificially causing any delay, please check my updated question, i added a GIF to showcase the issue

Comment: Hmm, very strange. Thanks for adding that. Does it behave the same with a delay [like the default values (500,2000)]?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I tried using the `ShowTypingMiddleware` and the `CustomShowTypingMiddleware` but they didn't work for me as expected. The message was sent before and after the typing indicator was shown. That is, the bot ended sending twice the same message (before the typing indicator and after the typing indicator was shown).

I was able to fix this issue using [Send a typing indicator code example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-send-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) which I implemented in the `OnMessageActivityAsync` handler.

```
await turnContext.SendActivitiesAsync(new Activity[] {
        new Activity { Type = ActivityTypes.Typing },
        new Activity { Type = "delay", Value= 3000 },
        MessageFactory.Text("Finished typing", "Finished typing"),
        }, cancellationToken);
```